# Создание генератора карт из 3д тайлов на Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Делаю подобие игры Pixel Dungeon, только в 3д варианте. Начал с генератора подземелий.
Задумка такая, есть некий набор 3д тайлов, из которых будет собираться случайная карта.

[image: Набор тайлов]

Я уже определил способ соединений этих тайлов между собой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На тайлах висит скрипт, в котором есть информация о точках стыка, я их именую анкорами.
Если есть свободный анкор у первого тайла и есть свободный анкор у второго, то я могу скрепить эти тайлы между собой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше я приступил к генератору, криво косо я пытался что-то сделать, но чего то путного у меня не вышло. Генератор просто случайно выбирал тайлы и прикреплял их. Разумного поведения я не увидел в генераторе. Точнее создатель не смог его туда вложить. В итоге я понял, что просто рандомно склеивая тайлы меж собой, не выйдет ничего хорошего. Дальше я начал думать, как переделать генератор.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока в голову пришли вот такие примерные шаги (ниже рисунок):

1. Собрать заранее большие комнаты из тайлов, и случайно расположить их на сцене.
2. Пустить лучи из анкоров (из красных квадратиков комнат).
3. На некой точке луча (красного), пустить другие перпендикулярные ей лучи (оранжевые лучи), чтобы точно получить пересечения.
4. Использовать каким-то образом пересечения лучей для построения коридоров.

Вопросы у меня возникают уже с первого пункта, как правильно устанавливать комнаты, чтобы они не спавнились в миллионах километров друг от друга, как правильно пускать лучи, чтоб они между собой пересекались (Physics.Rayсast() наверно не поможет) и еще куча мелких вопросов, возможно которые я смогу решить. Прошу помочь с основными пунктами.

Возможно я изобретаю велосипед, и уже давно существуют более изящные решения, но я пока не смог найти того, что мне подходит. Укажите мне пожалуйста дорогу. Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не смотря на то что вопрос недостаточно конкретизированный(что не очень по правилах), хочу похвалить за его оформление, за тематику вопроса и за хорошую подачу. Проделана прекрасная работа и изложение вопроса весьма хорошее.

Answer (score 2):

> как правильно устанавливать комнаты, чтобы они не спавнились в
> миллионах километров друг от друга

Думаю здесь нужно забыть что существует 3д и на секунду представить себе 2д карту видом сверху. Можно создать некое "поле" в котором есть сектора - квадратики. В каждый квадратик можно вставить 1-2 твоих примитива карты в случайном порядке (или псевдослучайном). Это решит и проблему милионов километров и ты всегда будешь контролировать какого размера карту нужно генерить. Вполне возможно что у генератора можно ввести дополнительные ограничения - например определенные примитивы карты не должны быть на одной клетке вместе или же повернутыми один на второго твоими анкорами.

Ну или, например, что некие примитивы нельзя ставить если в соседних клетках есть другие примитивы "несовместимые" с этим.

Еще в даном случае можно генерить примитив не в каждой клетке карты, а, например, используя PerlinNoise

> как правильно пускать лучи, чтоб они между собой пересекались

для этого в юнити есть RayCast. Для дебага - то ли RayRenderer то ли LineRenderer.
Но прийдется расчитывать куда пускать луч.

Если всегда перпендикулярно - нужно сделать твои примитивы так, что бы их анкоры всегда были в одних и тех же точках. То есть 2 разных примитива могут иметь анкор в одной и той же точке "клетки" в которой он будет находится в поле.

Если не всегда перпендикулярно - предлагаю анкоры помечать пустым обьектом с неким тегом, искать их при помощи физикс.сферОверлап по тегу "анкор" и соединять 2 ближайших анкора.

> На некой точке луча, пустить другие перпендикулярные ей лучи (оранжевые лучи).

Этой задумки я не понял, так что и прокоментировать никак не могу.

> Использовать каким-то образом пересечения лучей для построения коридоров.

Нагуглил вот это:

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/3d_Math_functions

LineLineIntersection() , ClosestPointOnTwoLines()

---

Вобщем сам с таким дела не имел, но такие вот мысли возникли по ходу прочтения вопроса. Буду рад если помог чем-либо :)

Comment: Для дебага вроде есть Debug.DrawRay() и Debyg.DrawLine()

Answer (score 1):

Определенно велосипед. Есть много разных подходов, с разными результатами и для комнат и для пещер. `Google: 2D Dungeon Generator`

Например подход в котором карта будет в неком прямоугольнике и генерация через его деление в случайных местах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Статья](https://eskerda.com/bsp-dungeon-generation/)

Более сложный подход через разброс по физике и триангуляции комнат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Статья](https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/AAdonaac/20150903/252889/Procedural_Dungeon_Generation_Algorithm.php)